# Ranges em diferentes colunas, mas mesma linha (VBA)

Tags: vba, range

Tenho 3 diferentes Ranges de valores diferentes, por exemplo:
Range1(a,b,c), Range2(d,e,f), Range3(g,h,f). Esses 3 ranges já ficam em colunas específicas da planilha, ou seja, o primeiro na coluna B, o segundo na C e o terceiro na D. Entretanto, preciso de um código que os distribua nessas colunas automaticamente de modo que eles nunca fiquem na mesma linha e por ordem de prioridade. Por exemplo: o Range 1, vai ficar distribuído na coluna B, ocupando as linhas  1, 2 e 3. O Range 3, na coluna C , ocupando as linhas 4 , 5, 6, e assim sucessivamente, de forma alternada. Poderiam ajudar?